# Search for a pattern in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I need to determine whether

> +review CR @someuser

exists in a string. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for the literal string `@someuser` or are you trying to capture a username following `@`?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to escape the meta characters and use a matching regex `m//`.

```
if ($string =~ /\+review CR \@someuser/) {
    # do something
}
```

Note that you cannot use the `\Q ... \E` escape sequence to escape the meta characters, since `@someuser` will still be interpolated. You could use it for the `+`, but then you would still need to escape the `@`, so this way is simpler. You can also use the `quotemeta` function. However, in this case that might be overkill.

Read more about this in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

Answer (score 1):

Use `index`:

`$search_string = "+review CR \@someuser";

  if (index($string, $search_string) != -1) { # found }`

Or, if you use a regex, you'll want to make sure the '+' and '@' are properly escaped:

`if ( $string =~ m#\+review CR \@someuser# ) {
    # found
}`

Comment: Escaping didn't make it through properly. Edited. Alternatively, `$search_string` could have been declared with single quotes.